# Spring @Scheduled working locally, but not in live server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a rest service that is supposed to call a function using @Scheduled. The other functions in `MyService` work as intended locally and in live, just not the scheduled function. Any ideas on what I am missing here that would cause it to fail only in live?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "elsewhere.yyy.yyy")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}

@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    MyService service;
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000, initialDelay = 10000)
    public void myTask() {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

I turned on debug logging, but am seeing no `org.springframework.scheduling.*` logs, my theory should be that spring just isn't seeing `@Scheduled` for some reason and is thus not running it, but it is working perfectly fine locally! My other theory is that `@Async` might be causing an unexpected interaction, but it doesn't make sense to me that it would cause the function to disappear in live only... The good(?) news is that is consistently not working in live and consistently working locally.

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.5.1

Comment: Strange the behavior is environment-dependant. You don't have any Spring `profiles` and profile-dependant configurations in your project, do you?

Comment: I do, the controller and service classes are under a profile, but the profile appears to be activated in both environments since the rest of the class's code is operating as intended. The live environment has a slightly different set of profiles, but since the other profiles should be completely independent of this, I would assume it should have no effect on this profile. Currently investigating whether that assumption is true.

Comment: Have a thorough look at profile-dependant configuration classes. Some profiles may disable or not enable the scheduling which would cause your service to initialize but not to put a scheduler on. I would also look at profile `.yml` or `.properties` configurations

Comment: One thing to check if all else fails is your system clock. If it's running on a VM you can get some weird clock drift that would mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an ID-10T error. `//Do Stuff...` early on looks for a file that may or may not be there, and short circuits as intended when the file isn't there. The file was provided and the silent short circuit in a live environment made it appear as if the scheduled task was simply never running. The issue was that I provided the file to the incorrect subdirectory, putting said file into the correct directory solved the issue.